# Is “so” different from “this” in these sentences?

Tags: word-difference

Here are the sentences:

> It was only **so long**. It was only **this long**.
>
> Is your dream only **so big**? Is your dream only **this big**?

I think they’re the same, but with different feelings that I couldn’t describe.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples of

> **so**
>   **this**

has a difference in nuance.  Both mean that *something* is *limited*.
By using "***so***" it is indeterminable in where the limit is: maybe a foot, maybe two feet. Using "***this***" has a specific limit.
However with additional context, both "***so***" and "***this***" may have exactly the same meaning.